# build gcc4.9 under suse10 some vars was not declared

Tags: suse

I build gcc4.9 with the following step

1. wget ftp://mirrors.kernel.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.9.0/gcc-4.9.0.tar.gz
2. tar -zxvf gcc-4.9.0.tar.gz
3. cd gcc-4.9.0
4. ./contrib/download_prerequisites
5. cd ..
6. mkdir gcc-build-4.9.0
7. cd gcc-build-4.9.0
8. ../gcc-4.9.0/configure --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib
9. make -j4

it show the error message:

```
../../../../gcc-4.9.0/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:232:27: error: ‘PTRACE_GETSIGINFO’ was not declared in this scope
   int ptrace_getsiginfo = PTRACE_GETSIGINFO;
                           ^
../../../../gcc-4.9.0/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:233:27: error: ‘PTRACE_SETSIGINFO’ was not declared in this scope
   int ptrace_setsiginfo = PTRACE_SETSIGINFO;
                           ^
../../../../gcc-4.9.0/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:390:30: error: ‘EVIOCGREP’ was not declared in this scope
   unsigned IOCTL_EVIOCGREP = EVIOCGREP;
                              ^
../../../../gcc-4.9.0/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:399:30: error: ‘EVIOCSREP’ was not declared in this scope
   unsigned IOCTL_EVIOCSREP = EVIOCSREP;
                              ^
../../../../gcc-4.9.0/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:682:36: error: ‘FS_IOC_GETFLAGS’ was not declared in this scope
   unsigned IOCTL_FS_IOC_GETFLAGS = FS_IOC_GETFLAGS;
                                    ^
../../../../gcc-4.9.0/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:683:38: error: ‘FS_IOC_GETVERSION’ was not declared in this scope
   unsigned IOCTL_FS_IOC_GETVERSION = FS_IOC_GETVERSION;
                                      ^
../../../../gcc-4.9.0/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:684:36: error: ‘FS_IOC_SETFLAGS’ was not declared in this scope
   unsigned IOCTL_FS_IOC_SETFLAGS = FS_IOC_SETFLAGS;
                                    ^
../../../../gcc-4.9.0/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:685:38: error: ‘FS_IOC_SETVERSION’ was not declared in this scope
   unsigned IOCTL_FS_IOC_SETVERSION = FS_IOC_SETVERSION;
                                      ^
make[4]: *** [sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.lo] Error 1
```

I try to rebuild, but it show the error again.